# Storing large mutable arrays on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, file, nsmutablearray

Okay, I can't seem to find a clear answer to this question of storage on the iPhone.  My model class has several ivars and two very large (MB) mutable arrays of data that are collected from an external device and then analyzed.  What I'm thinking is that you have data in the object (similar to a note or a music file) and you can save it to a permanent data "file", and then later open old data "file" and view it (no editing of old data will be done). Along side this I want another stored object that keeps track of a few key bits of information from each of the data files, and also has references to them (maybe the user could click a data point, and it would open the corresponding data file - if it still exists (it could be deleted by the user to save space)).

I see tons of advice recommending all data storage for iPhone apps should use Core Data.  The thing is, except for the one side "file", there are no relationships between objects.  The objects could be thought of as notes or music files, they don't care about the existence of each other, and there is only one object in existence ("loaded") at a time (either in memory with data being added to it, and to be saved later, or loaded from storage being viewed).

What is the best way to manage this?  Currently a device controller (handles the device communication) creates the model, and sends data to it (the model parses and analyzes the data).  But should there be some controller that handles files (or Core Data managedobject, whatever) that creates the object, and the saves its data, releases its memory and then loads a new one with stored data?

Any advice would be helpful, as the best storage examples I've found seem to be very relational (employee,boss,company) - which I can see would benefit from a database.  But at the same time, manually keeping a list of files in a directory may be more work than some other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find citation in Apple's documentation but I have read (and been told by Apple engineers) that "large" data objects are sometimes best stored outside of Core Data. The model that has been suggested places BLOBs (Binary Large OBjects) in file system with Core Data objects referencing these large objects (i.e., storing relative or absolute file paths).

So, assuming that your BLOBs are music data, then you might have your Core Data model have an entity that holds meta-data (e.g., size, time/duration, etc.) as well as reference to file that holds actual data. Your meta-data entity could also have relationships with other entities within your system. For example, you might store spectrograms for music data and have those held by a separate entity.

I wrestled with this issue for data that was being sampled from various measurement sensors. Ultimately, I decided that my data sets were small enough (in most cases) to store with Core Data as NSData properties of dedicated entity. The wrapping entity was 'dedicated' so as to avoid loading data just to display meta-data to user.

**Update**

I found line about BLOBs in Core Data Programming Guide at the end of the "Large Data Objects (BLOBs)" section:

> It is better, however, if you are able
>   to store BLOBs as resources on the
>   filesystem, and to maintain links
>   (such as URLs or paths) to those
>   resources. You can then load a BLOB as
>   and when necessary.

Comment: Your mention of spectrograms caught my eye, as that is what is stored in one array (the other being the raw data, which is much smaller in size). Your prior use sounds closer to what I am doing, (than all an address book, or simple model-view connected apps I've seen (the data are arrays that are directly taken for the view - some even build the view-CoreD connections in IB)) that I'm curious if you have any advice on the app layout (controller & model hierarchy), or even some sources because the CoreD Developer documentation is so general, with some strange lingo, as to be almost unreadable.

Comment: I haven't used spectrograms but was reading Shazam papers yesterday, so that came to mind. The app that I mentioned organizes 'experiments' - which are collections of 'runs' with each run containing an arbitrary number of 'samples' (one for each sampled measurement). That is fairly standard Core Data (e.g., Recipes). The data for each sample is unbounded; one could, in theory, sample at 1000Hz for hours. In actual use samples tend to be less than 1MB (much less), so NSData attribute in Core Data suffices. If data lives in Core Data, then design so as to minimize unnecessary loading of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend using Core Data. While Core Data does make it easy to handle relations, no one is preventing you from using Core Data to store unrelated information. There is no rule against creating models in Core Data that have no relation with each other what so ever; just don't link them together.

Core Data will handle all the reading/writing to the database, which will save you the trouble of having to parse your own files. There is a bit of a learning curve when trying to use Core Data for the first time, but once you get it running, you'll be thankful it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need any kind of database access (fast queries, frequent updates, etc.), a database involves too much overhead, in terms of both coding and performance. Database features are not exactly free, so I can think of a lot of scenarios where you will get better results with less effort if you go with one of the following:

- multiple files with a separately stored index file;
- a large file of your own binary format.

The choice depends on the number of items, the size of items, whether their sizes are identical, how often you need to modify the data and/or the index, etc.